# OpenCL CodeXL Profiler executes the kernel several times

Tags: profiling, opencl, gpu, amd-processor

I'm trying to profile some Opencl code with CodeXL (or more to the point sprofile). This always gives me the wrong output when profiling in performancecounter mode (but not when using the trace option `-t`), so I tried to find out why. After some experimentations I concluded that each kernel is executed three times leading to wrong results for kernels which modify some existing data instead of overwriting it. The following toy program showcases this behaviour.

**My question is: Does anyohne have an idea why it behaves like that and how to stop it from doing so?**

My OS is Fedora Linux 18
CodeXL Version : CodeXL-Linux-1.1.1537.0
Graphic Card: ATI Technologies Inc Device 6798

here is the execute command:

```
   /opt/CodeXL-Linux-1.1.1537.0-x86_64-release/Output_x86_64/release/bin/x86_64/sprofile -o example.csv -w . OpenCLExample
```

my code:

```
    cl_context CreateContext()
   {
       cl_int errNum;
       cl_uint numPlatforms;
       cl_platform_id firstPlatformId;
       cl_context context = NULL;
       errNum = clGetPlatformIDs(1,&firstPlatformId, &numPlatforms);
       cl_context_properties contextProperties[] =
       {
            CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
            (cl_context_properties)firstPlatformId,
            0
       };
       context = clCreateContextFromType(contextProperties,CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,
                 NULL,NULL,&errNum);

       return context;
   }

   cl_command_queue CreateCommandQueue(cl_context context,cl_device_id *device)
   {
        cl_int errNum;
        cl_device_id *devices;
        cl_command_queue commandQueue = NULL;
        size_t deviceBufferSize = -1;

        errNum = clGetContextInfo(context,CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES,0,NULL,&deviceBufferSize);

        devices = new cl_device_id[deviceBufferSize/sizeof(cl_device_id)];
        errNum = clGetContextInfo(context,CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES,deviceBufferSize,devices,NULL);

        commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(context,devices[0],0,NULL);

        *device = devices[0];
        delete[] devices;
        return commandQueue;
   }

   cl_program CreateProgram(cl_context context,cl_device_id device,const char* filename)
   {
        cl_int errNum;
        cl_program program;

        std::ifstream kernelFile(filename,std::ios::in);
        kernelFile.is_open();

        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << kernelFile.rdbuf();

        std::string srcStdStr = oss.str();
        const char *srcStr = srcStdStr.c_str();
        program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context,1,
                                           (const char**)&srcStr,
                                           NULL,NULL);    

        errNum = clBuildProgram(program,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
        return program;
    }


    bool CreateMemObjects(cl_context context,cl_mem memObjects[3],float *a,float *b)
    {
       memObjects[0] = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                       sizeof(float)*ARRAY_SIZE,a,NULL);
       memObjects[1] = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                       sizeof(float)*ARRAY_SIZE,b,NULL);
       memObjects[2] = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
                       sizeof(float)*ARRAY_SIZE,NULL,NULL);

       return true;
    }

     int main(int arg,char** argv)
    {
         cl_context context=0;
         cl_command_queue commandQueue = 0;
         cl_program program = 0;
         cl_device_id device = 0;
         cl_kernel kernel = 0;
         cl_mem memObjects[3] = {0,0,0};
         cl_int errNum;

         context = CreateContext(); 
         commandQueue = CreateCommandQueue(context,&device);
         program = CreateProgram(context,device,"Example.cl");
         kernel = clCreateKernel(program,"example_kernel",NULL);

         float result[ARRAY_SIZE];
         float a[ARRAY_SIZE];
         float b[ARRAY_SIZE];
         for(int i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++)
         {
            a[i] = i;
            b[i] = i*2;
         }

         if(!CreateMemObjects(context,memObjects,a,b))
             return 1;

         errNum = clSetKernelArg(kernel,0,sizeof(cl_mem),&memObjects[0]);
         errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kernel,1,sizeof(cl_mem),&memObjects[1]);
         errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kernel,2,sizeof(cl_mem),&memObjects[2]);

         size_t globalWorkSize[1] = {ARRAY_SIZE};
         size_t localWorkSize[1] = { 1 };

         errNum = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue,kernel,1,NULL,globalWorkSize,localWorkSize,0,
         NULL,NULL);

         errNum = clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue,memObjects[2], CL_TRUE,
         0,ARRAY_SIZE*sizeof(float),result,
         0,NULL,NULL);

         return 0;

     }
```

kernel:

```
    #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_amd_printf : enable

    kernel void example_kernel(global const float *a,
                               global const float *b,
                               global float *result)
    {
         int gid = get_global_id(0);
         result[gid] = a[gid] * b[gid];
         printf((__constant char *)"DEBUG: example_kernel id: %d result: %g\n", gid, result[gid]);
    }
```

This is what I get as a result:

```
    DEBUG: example_kernel id: 0 result: 0
    DEBUG: example_kernel id: 1 result: 2
    DEBUG: example_kernel id: 2 result: 8
    DEBUG: example_kernel id: 3 result: 18
    DEBUG: example_kernel id: 0 result: 0
    DEBUG: example_kernel id: 1 result: 2
    DEBUG: example_kernel id: 2 result: 8
    DEBUG: example_kernel id: 3 result: 18
    DEBUG: example_kernel id: 0 result: 0
    DEBUG: example_kernel id: 1 result: 2
    DEBUG: example_kernel id: 2 result: 8
    DEBUG: example_kernel id: 3 result: 18
```

Comment: What version of Catalyst Driver Version are you using ? I have the RHEL 6.2 with same hardware config, I don't see this problem

Comment: Have you tried running the program with commenting cl_amd_printf opencl extension, printf statements, I believe CodeXL/Profiler Debugger doesn't support printf statements.

Comment: thanks for your reply. My Catalyst Driver is AMD Catalyst™ 13.4 Proprietary Linux. Does my code above working on your system? And it isn't executed three times?

Comment: the printf is only for debugging. This behavior still appears without the printf option (and my other kernels) as well. hhhmmm maybe it have something to do with my Linux Kernel Version (3.8.12-100.fc17.x86_64)?

Comment: could be, I tried your code can't repro on Ubuntu 12.04 or RHEL 6.2 machines. For Debugging you can use GPU Debugger available in CodeXL and remove your printf statements

Comment: You could try a more low-level profiling with http://fakenmc.github.io/cf4ocl/, so you can control at all times what is going on. (I developed this OpenCL profiler due to similar problems with CodeXL and other profilers)

Answer (score 1):

It behaves this way because the GPU profiler replays the kernel a few times, in order to be able to collect the values of all relevant hardware counters (there is a limit for the number of hardware counters that can be queried during a single kernel's run). A helpful answer is provided here: http://devgurus.amd.com/message/1297746